# Inserting decimals in string with Presto

Tags: sql, presto

My Presto query is returning coordinates (latitude and longitude) as a string with no decimal.  In order to use these values further on in the query, however, the decimal needs to be inserted.

```
{"latitude":37463030,"longitude":-122234966,"timestamp":1556991970"}
```

The first value `latitutde` would need a decimal after two places, and the second value `longitude` would need a decimal after three places.

As far as I know, you need a delimiter in order to split a string with `split(string, delimiter)`.  What if you just want to insert character after two places in the first case, and after three places in the second case?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about treating the values as numbers and dividing?

```
select cast(-122234966 as numeric(20, 7)) / 10000000
```

I am unclear on why you would want to store such values as strings in the first place.

Comment: that's an engineering question)